# Manage data downloaded from url - swift

Tags: swift, xcode, parsing, url, swift4

I have two URLs from which to download data and these give me json of this kind :

1) http://192.168.178.77/MyWebService/api/getteams.php

R ->

```
{"teams":
[{"id":1,"name":"Avengers","member":7},{"id":2,"name":"Fantastics4","member":4},{"id":3,"name":"test","member":6},{"id":4,"name":"teamtest","member":33},{"id":5,"name":"inserisco","member":33},{"id":6,"name":"sarto","member":33},
{"id":7,"name":"name","member":22},
{"id":8,"name":"test","member":999}]
}
```

2)http://127.0.0.1/MyWebService/api/fetch_image.php?id_team=1 //Where id_team param is an id downloaded from the first URL

R -> `{"image_team":[{"id":4,"img_path":"http:\/\/localhost\/MyWebService\/images\/imgTest.png","id_team":1}]}`

Now, to download this data, in swift I have created classes and functions to contain and download data.

the 2 classes located in the respective file.swift are:

1)in TeamJson.swift :

```
import Foundation

class ClassJsonTeam: Codable {

    private var teams: [JsonTeam]

    init(teams: [JsonTeam]) {
        self.teams = teams
    }

    func getTeams()-> [JsonTeam]{
        return(self.teams);
    }

    func setTeams(teams:[JsonTeam]){
        self.teams = teams;
    }

}

class JsonTeam: Codable {
    private let id: Int
    private var name: String
    private var member: Int

    init(id: Int, name: String, member: Int) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.member = member
    }

    func getId()->Int{
        return(self.id);
    }

    func setId(id:Int){
        self.member = id;
    }

    func getName()->String{
        return(self.name);
    }

    func setName(name:String){
        self.name = name;
    }

    func getMembers()->Int{
        return(self.member);
    }

    func setMembers(members:Int){
        self.member = members;
    }
}
```

2) in ImageJsonTeam.swift

```
import Foundation

class ClassJsonTeamImage : Codable {
    private var teams : [JsonTeamImg]

    init(teams: [JsonTeamImg]) {
        self.teams = teams
    }

    func getTeamsImg()-> [JsonTeamImg]{
        return(self.teams);
    }

    func setTeamsImg(teams:[JsonTeamImg]){
        self.teams = teams;
    }
}

class JsonTeamImg : Codable{
    private var id : Int
    private var imagePath: URL
    private var teamId : Int

    init(id : Int, imagePath : URL , teamId : Int) {
        self.id = id
        self.imagePath = imagePath
        self.teamId = teamId
    }

    func getId() -> Int{
        return(self.id)
    }

    func setId(id : Int){
        self.id = id
    }

    func  getImagePath() -> URL {
        return(self.imagePath)
    }

    func setImagePath(imagePath : URL){
        self.imagePath = imagePath
    }

    func getTeamId()-> Int{
        return(self.teamId)
    }

    func setTeamId(teamId : Int){
        self.teamId = teamId
    }
}
```

moreover, since I need to merge the information from the two jsons, I created a third class of this type:

3)CompleteTeamJson.swift

```
import Foundation

public class ClassJsonCompleteTeam{
    private var team : [JsonCompleteTeam]

    init(team : [JsonCompleteTeam]){
        self.team = team
    }
}

public class JsonCompleteTeam{
    private var id : Int
    private var name : String
    private var member : Int
    private var imgUrl : URL

    init(id: Int, name: String, member: Int, imgUrl: URL) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.member = member
        self.imgUrl = imgUrl
    }

    func getId()->Int{
        return(self.id);
    }

    func setId(id:Int){
        self.member = id;
    }

    func getName()->String{
        return(self.name);
    }

    func setName(name:String){
        self.name = name;
    }

    func getMembers()->Int{
        return(self.member);
    }

    func setMembers(members:Int){
        self.member = members;
    }

    func  getImageUrl() -> URL {
        return(self.imgUrl)
    }

    func setImagePath(imgUrl : URL){
        self.imgUrl = imgUrl
    }

}
```

Now, the situation in my viewController is this:

```
import UIKit

//var teamCollection  : ClassJsonTeam!
//
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func InsertNewTeamButton(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "NewTeamSegue", sender: self)
    }

    var teams: [JsonTeam]?
    var teamsImg : [JsonTeamImg]?
    var teamsComplete : [JsonCompleteTeam]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        downloadTeams(completion: { (teams) in

            self.teams = teams

            for index in (0...(self.teams!.count - 1)){

                self.downloadTeamsImage(idTeam: teams[index].getId(), completion:
                    {(teamsImg) in self.teamsImg = teamsImg
                })
                let finalId : Int = teams[index].getId()
                let finalName : String = teams[index].getName()
                let finalMember : Int = teams[index].getMembers()
                var finalURL : URL = URL(string : "http://localhost/MyWebService/images/EmptyImg.png")!

                for index2 in (0...(self.teamsImg!.count - 1)){
                    if (finalId == self.teamsImg![index2].getId()){
                        finalURL = self.teamsImg![index2].getImagePath()
                    }
                }

                let tempCompleteTeam = JsonCompleteTeam(id: finalId, name: finalName, member: finalMember, imgUrl: finalURL)
                self.teamsComplete?.append(tempCompleteTeam)


            }

            //self.InsertNewTeamButton((Any).self)
            self.showTeamButton((Any).self)

        })
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // somethings in new wc //
    }


    @IBAction func showTeamButton(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "TeamListSegue", sender: self)
    }

    func downloadTeams(completion: @escaping (([JsonTeam]) -> Void)) {
        //get teams with classes
        let getTeamUrl = "http://192.168.178.77/MyWebService/api/getteams.php"

        guard let urlTeam = URL(string: getTeamUrl) else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlTeam) { (data,response,err) in
            guard let data = data else {return}
            do {
                let team = try JSONDecoder().decode(ClassJsonTeam.self, from: data)
                var tempArrayTeam = [JsonTeam]()
                for index in 0...(team.getTeams().count - 1) {

                    let tempTeam = JsonTeam(id: team.getTeams()[index].getId(),
                                            name: team.getTeams()[index].getName(),
                                            member: team.getTeams()[index].getMembers())

                    print(team.getTeams()[index].getId())
                    print(team.getTeams()[index].getName())
                    print(team.getTeams()[index].getMembers())

                    tempArrayTeam.append(tempTeam)
                }
                completion(tempArrayTeam)
            } catch let jsonErr{
                print("Error serializing json: \(jsonErr.localizedDescription)")
            }
            }.resume()
    }

    func downloadTeamsImage(idTeam: Int,completion: @escaping (([JsonTeamImg]) -> Void)) {
        //get teams with classes
        let getTeamUrl = "http://127.0.0.1/MyWebService/api/fetch_image.php?id_team=\(idTeam)"

        guard let urlTeam = URL(string: getTeamUrl) else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlTeam) { (data,response,err) in
            guard let data = data else {return}
            do {
                let team = try JSONDecoder().decode(ClassJsonTeamImage.self, from: data)
                var tempArrayTeamImg = [JsonTeamImg]()
                for index in 0...(team.getTeamsImg().count - 1) {

                    let tempTeamImg = JsonTeamImg(id: team.getTeamsImg()[index].getId(),
                                               imagePath: team.getTeamsImg()[index].getImagePath(),
                                               teamId: team.getTeamsImg()[index].getTeamId())

                    print(tempTeamImg.getId())
                    print(tempTeamImg.getImagePath())
                    print(tempTeamImg.getTeamId())

                    tempArrayTeamImg.append(tempTeamImg)
                }
                completion(tempArrayTeamImg)
            } catch let jsonErr{
                print("Error serializing json: \(jsonErr.localizedDescription)")
            }
            }.resume()
    }

}
```

Let's get to the point: if I call the two functions individually, of course they work but I don't know how to incorporate the data downloaded into the do-catch outside of this (for example in the two variables teams and in teamsImg ) so that we can contribute the variable       teamsComplete and transport the data in another view controller.

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: You have set all your data in the desired variables you can do what ever you want with that data and can access them anywhere, what is your problem here?

Comment: @RaziTiwana The problem is that datatask works on another thread and therefore, in the viewDidLoad I should wait before the functions finish downloading data before being able to do operations with these.
In fact the app goes crush on this line : for index2 in (0...(self.teamsImg!.count - 1)){ 

and the error is : Thread 5: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: First, It should crash there as your `self.teamsImg` is nil at that point. Second, you should mentioned this in the question. Now you only have to move this code in the completion. Assuming this is the only problem here.

Comment: Are pointing about operation dependency here? like, do you want to get notified when your data ready from both the operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update You `viewDidLoad`

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        downloadTeams(completion: { (teams) in

            self.teams = teams

            for index in (0...(self.teams!.count - 1)){
                self.downloadTeamsImage(idTeam: teams[index].getId(), completion:
                    {(teamsImg) in self.teamsImg = teamsImg

                let finalId : Int = teams[index].getId()
                let finalName : String = teams[index].getName()
                let finalMember : Int = teams[index].getMembers()
                var finalURL : URL = URL(string : "http://localhost/MyWebService/images/EmptyImg.png")!

                for index2 in (0...(self.teamsImg!.count - 1)){
                    if (finalId == self.teamsImg![index2].getId()){
                        finalURL = self.teamsImg![index2].getImagePath()
                    }
                }

                let tempCompleteTeam = JsonCompleteTeam(id: finalId, name: finalName, member: finalMember, imgUrl: finalURL)
                self.teamsComplete?.append(tempCompleteTeam)

                // YOU CAN MOVE FORWARD NOW AS ALL THE DATA IS LOADED 
                if index == self.teams!.count - 1 {
                   self.showTeamButton((Any).self)
                }

             }
           })

        })
    }
```

This will remove your crash and will call `showTeamButton` when all the data is loaded.